# PHP & MySQL - Generate own unique reference

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently coding a web application which I will need to create unique reference for quotes and invoices.

I wanted to create a reference that included the year and month then an reference number. i.e YYYY-MM-001.

The web application will be multi tenant and several users will be using it at the same time. One of my concerns is, how would I generate my reference without it be duplicated at the same time if there is multiple users doing the same request at the same time?

What would be the best way for me to approach this?

I am using PHP 8 and a MySQL database.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the native identity/autoincrement functionality, that has been baked in to relational databases since their inception? Using an identifier to also include implicit information (such as a date) is an anti-pattern, it should be avoided; identifiers should Only assert unique identity, and not explicitly or implicitly contain any other information. Store that associated data in the table in columns explicitly for that purpose.

Comment: I have read several replies on Stack Overflow which has discouraged the use of auto increment which has clouded my judgement somewhat. AI was my initial thought but how would I reset it to match the start of a new year or month?

Comment: if you really wanna include that `YYYY-MM` I would recommend using ***Youtube*** approach by using a random 11 char base64 ref instead of incremented numbers. So ID would be something like `2022-12-xA0TR1xZc2n`

Comment: `replies on Stack Overflow which has discouraged the use of auto increment`...please do quote them, in case they're relevant (or not). It would be interesting to know the reason, because that's a very unusual approach.

Comment: Anyone discouraging use of autoincrement doesn't understand relational databases. They're fundamental to their design and implementation. *(You **don't** reset identity values on arbitrary boundaries. The identity shouldn't care about anything other than unique identification of an entity. Anything else goes elsewhere in the table. This is an XY problem. Please ask a new question with your functional need, instead of asking how to implement an anti-pattern solution)*.

Comment: You should auto-generate an ID to uniquely identify the row. If you want to show a different reference number to end-users, you can generate that as a function of the ID and a timestamp/datestamp column which you can put in the same row in the database. This avoids your concern, because the database guarantees that the auto-increment values are unique within each table.

Comment: I would love to use AI but my concern is that I will possibly end up with a really long number such as 2024-01-012733 instead of it starting off as 2024-01-001, as a result of it auto incrementing. I understand why that will occur but I wanted it user friendly and to restart for each year

Comment: @ADyson I currently have this setup, I have an ID that auto increments for each row. So the reference is just for the user as a friendly reference. I did think about adding a timestamp but I'm concerned that someone may send the request at the same time and will end up with the same timestamp

Comment: This site uses autoincrement for questions, answers, users... isn't it friendly to you?

Comment: Identities DON'T include dates. The date goes elsewhere in the table. In relational databases identifiers ONLY uniquely identify an entity. Stop trying to use a hammer to drive a screw. Use the technology in the way it has been designed to be used, succesfully for decades. Start asking the question "if hyperscale sites succesfully avoid needing this, why am I convinced differently?" You're not a uniquely special genius that has discovered an oversight present for decades, you simply don't ***yet*** fully understand the correct and successful patterns.

Comment: you can give UNIQUE index to your column. So when there is a duplicate value entered, your query will give an error. If you get error then regenerate your user-friendly ID and run your insert query again

Comment: @Bhavik that's really inefficient though

Comment: Are you saying you want to restart the numbers from 001 every month? Again you can do that as a presentational thing, but don't confuse that with generating a genuinely unique ID for the database row itself.

Comment: your id column will work as it is. unique and auto incremental. he can have a new column created which he can use for user presentation

Comment: @ADyson I would like to restart on a new year. However my problem would be that I would need to retrieve the previous reference one first to increment but then could face that another user may have already committed the same reference before the initial user

Comment: Ok. I see no reason to do any restarting, to be honest. If your users want to count how many invoices have been generated in a single year (or any other time period), you can give them a report to run about it. The sequence number of any individual invoice should be entirely unimportant in day to day operations. Again, it's simply a way to uniquely identify it. It's really unclear why you think this numbering would be helpful to anyone. Has anyone given a specific justification for why they might want this, or is it just something you've decided to do?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the primary key id or any unique column, then don't worry about the uniqueness of the data.
Use that column/id to generate a unique reference as follows :

```
update invoices
set reference = concat(date_format(now(), "%Y-%m-00"), unique_id)
where unique_id = 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're sure you won't have more than 999 quotes/invoices in one month, you could do something like the following...

```
CREATE TABLE quotes (
  id INT(14) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  YMFqid char(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (YMFqid));

CREATE TABLE YMnext (
  YM char(7) NOT NULL,
  next INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (YM));
```

Then to get the next values, you'll need some queries like...

```
SELECT next AS latest FROM YMnext WHERE YM = '2022-12';

INSERT INTO YMnext VALUES ('2022-12', 0);

UPDATE YMnext SET next = next + 1 WHERE YM = '2022-12' AND next = latest;
```

If the SELECT fails, then you insert, otherwise you update AND check that one and only one row was updated. If there's a chance you could have more than 999 quotes in a month, then you can alter the column sizes accordingly.

Comment: This is full of race conditions.

Comment: I don't see where. Please explain then...